# Open source softwares for editing a macromedia flashplayer animation

Tags: animation

I do not have any prior exposure to animation and thsi is teh first time that I am going to edit a file. 
I have an animation file as an EXE file. In the properties it says `Description:    Macromedia Flash Player 8.0  r22`

Please tell me an open source software which I can use to edit some of the frames.

Comment: Can a flash editor accept .exe file ?

Comment: You'd have to [decompile it](http://bit.ly/1vdsJii) if you don't have the original files

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about graphic design.

Comment: bit harsh on the downvotes..

Answer (score 1):

There are no open source programs becouse flash is a propietary technology.

So you need to use the adobe flash software. You can use it in a trial period of some days.

First you need to decompile the exe.

The only free usable program I ever found to make simple flash animations, for example a banner, is http://vectorian.com/ but it can not open swf files. Just export some basic animations into swf.